# Convert JSON format to pandas dataframe source postgresql

Tags: python, string, postgresql, dataframe, connection

I want to convert a json file from a postgresql source into a pandas dataframe

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
# Construct connection string
conn_string = ("CONNECTION_STRING")
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
conn.autocommit = True
cur = conn.cursor()
conn.commit()
##Exportando 
EXPORT="""SELECT * FROM Table"""
EXPORT=pd.read_sql(EXPORT, conn)
EXPORT
```

My current output is:

```
id  metadata    createdAt   updatedAt   version enabled carData  
priceData   userData    scheduleData    finished    appraisalData
250 {}  2021-09-15 16:23:06.252405+00:00    2021-09-15 
16:23:06.266376+00:00   2   True    {'plate': xxxxxx', 'brand': 'MAZDA', 
'model'...  {'value': '14500000', 'type': 'buy', 'page': '...   {'name': 
'Andrés', 'lastname': 'xxxxx', 'phone...    {'date': '2021-09- 
16T16:19:59.744Z', 'time': '... True    {'state': 'AGENDADA', 'origin': 
'widget', 'sel..
```

My desidered Output (columns)

```
 id metadata    createdAt   updatedAt   version enabled Plate   Brand    
 Model  Value   Type    Name    LastName    Phone   Date    Time
```

The issue is that I am getting inside of each column ,the content inside is json format, how can I fix my code in order to get pandas dataframe format of each column?

Comment: Can you provide a snapshot or something else that shows the output you're currently getting, and then show in some way what the desired output is?

Comment: If you have multiple columns each with json payloads, are you sure you even want to try to flatten them in a single dataframe?

Comment: Yes I am sure, That Is what I need

Answer (score 0):

Demonstrating it using a sample table with few selected columns provided in the post.

**Table**:

```
create table jsontab
(
 id int,
  version int,
  enabled boolean,
  cardata jsonb,
  pricedata jsonb
);

insert into jsontab values(250,2,true,'{"plate":"ABCD1234","brand":"mazda","model":"CX-5"}','{"value":"14500000","type":"buy"}');
insert into jsontab values(251,3,true,'{"plate":"WXYZ4321","brand":"subaru","model":"Forrster"}','{"value":"15000000","type":"buy"}');

postgres=> select * from jsontab;
 id  | version | enabled |                            cardata                            |              pricedata
-----+---------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------
 250 |       2 | t       | {"brand": "mazda", "model": "CX-5", "plate": "ABCD1234"}      | {"type": "buy", "value": "14500000"}
 251 |       3 | t       | {"brand": "subaru", "model": "Forrster", "plate": "WXYZ4321"} | {"type": "buy", "value": "15000000"}
(2 rows)

postgres=> select id,version,enabled,cardata->>'brand' "brand" , cardata->>'model' "model" , cardata->>'plate' "plate" , pricedata->>'type' "type" , pricedata->>'value' "value"  from jsontab;
 id  | version | enabled | brand  |  model   |  plate   | type |  value
-----+---------+---------+--------+----------+----------+------+----------
 250 |       2 | t       | mazda  | CX-5     | ABCD1234 | buy  | 14500000
 251 |       3 | t       | subaru | Forrster | WXYZ4321 | buy  | 15000000
(2 rows)
```

**Pandas** Dataframe (json retrieved as columns from within database):

```
>>> import pg8000 as dbapi
>>> conn = dbapi.connect(host='00.000.000.000',database='postgres',port=5432 , user='abcdefgh',password='xxxxxxx')
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_sql(r'''select id,version,enabled,cardata->>'brand' "brand" , cardata->>'model' "model" , cardata->>'plate' "plate" , pricedata->>'type' "type" , pricedata->>'value' "value"  from jsontab''',conn);
>>> df
    id  version  enabled   brand     model     plate type     value
0  250        2     True   mazda      CX-5  ABCD1234  buy  14500000
1  251        3     True  subaru  Forrster  WXYZ4321  buy  15000000
>>>
```

**Pandas** Dataframe (json processed in the python program)

```
import pg8000 as dbapi
import pandas as pd
conn = dbapi.connect(host='00.000.000.000',database='postgres',port=5432 , user='abcdefgh',password='xxxxxxx')
df = None
sql = '''select * from jsontab'''
curr = conn.cursor()
curr.execute(sql)
for row in curr.fetchall():
    non_json_dict = {'id':row[0],'version':row[1],'enabled':row[2]}
    json_cardata_dict = row[3]
    json_pricedata_dict = row[4]
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([{**non_json_dict,**json_cardata_dict,**json_pricedata_dict}])
    if df is None:
        df = temp_df
    else:
        df = pd.concat([df,temp_df])
curr.close() 
print(df)

Output:
$ python pandas1.py 
    id  version  enabled   brand     model     plate type     value
0  250        2     True   mazda      CX-5  ABCD1234  buy  14500000
0  251        3     True  subaru  Forrster  WXYZ4321  buy  15000000
```

Comment: which lenguage are you using on explanation of "Table" (R or Pyton)??

Comment: python which was tagged in the post..

Comment: Let me know if you need me to explain any part of this answer. I will detail it.